# Unflag a Question

Tags: feature-request, discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Flag removal: Is it possible to remove your flag or otherwise indicate it should be unflagged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87660/flag-removal-is-it-possible-to-remove-your-flag-or-otherwise-indicate-it-should)

In the interest of saving other people time... if I flag a question for moderation is there any way I can remove that flag?  If a user puts up a low quality question, and then later edits this to improv the quality of the question so the flag is no longer relevant, is there any way that I can (or should be able to) revoke the flag that I placed on this question?  Sorry if this post is mis-tagged.