# Unflag previously flagged posts

Tags: feature-request, flags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we have a way to undo a flag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96950/can-we-have-a-way-to-undo-a-flag)
>   [Should there be an option to revoke not yet reviewed flags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110065/should-there-be-an-option-to-revoke-not-yet-reviewed-flags)

I know we've covered this ground before in [Unflag a Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88074/unflag-a-question), but I haven't seen a feature request, so I'm creating one now.

Can we add a feature on the flagging history screen to unflag a post? I've got a pending low-quality flag that I'd like to kill, because the original question has been updated to higher quality.

Comment: Actually, there's quite a few versions of this request, mostly from this year: http://www.google.com/search?q=site:meta.stackoverflow.com+undo+flag You can also try "remove" or "cancel" instead of "undo".

Comment: Not to mention that the question you linked to is, in fact, tagged [tag:feature-request].