# Searching for "Tetris" doesn't find "Tetris'ing"

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Partial Word Search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88075/partial-word-search)

Searching for

```
user:187606 Tetris
```

doesn't find my question

[Tetris-ing an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3275258/tetrising-an-array)

Is this a bug? (feel free to remove the bug tag if it's not, but it feels like one to me.)

Comment: @random this is not a stemming issue, is it? It's about `'` not being treated as a word delimiter

Comment: Partially related: [Search and Unicode characters](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104295)

Comment: Sure feels like a stemming issue where the apostrophe would be part of the whole word