# A way to take back a flag for moderator attention if it was done accidentally

Tags: support, flags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Removing a flag or otherwise indicate that it should be unflagged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87660/removing-a-flag-or-otherwise-indicate-that-it-should-be-unflagged)

I am not sure if there is a way to do this today. I think it would be nice to have a way to take back/retract `a flag for moderator attention` if someone did it accidentally (ie. mis-clicked).

I have accidentally clicked while reviewing posts couple of times. It would be nice to immediately go back and take it out of moderator attention queue.

Comment: @random - sorry this question didnt pop up in the list when I was posting it. Thanks!