# Change or reverse flag

Tags: feature-request, flags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Flag removal: Is it possible to remove your flag or otherwise indicate it should be unflagged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87660/flag-removal-is-it-possible-to-remove-your-flag-or-otherwise-indicate-it-should)

This is a feature request to be able to change or undo a flag. I had situations where both scenarios were needed.

1. I flagged and not a question and OP went and expanded upon question making it valid.
2. I accidentally choose the wrong site when choosing off topic.

I feel like both of those could be common scenarios.

Comment: While they are fairly common, they are rather quickly dealt with. I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Agree, but with the flag weight feature invalid flags can effect your weight.

Comment: I don't, but it is a consequence of the action.

Comment: I think it would be a good feature. Is that not what the feature request tag is for. Regardless of weight, clearing a flag that I consider invalid is a good thing IMO.

Comment: I am defending it, flag weight not being important to me is not me giving in. Even with this conversation I still feel it is appropriate. More so, you can down vote if you like, or don't like I should say.

Comment: Final comment, I do not want to change flag weight. I want to provide accurate flags that is all. End of story and discussion.

Comment: Then I revert to my very original point. "While those occurrences are fairly common, they are dealt with rather quickly. I wouldn't worry about it."