# Add ability to retract a flag

Tags: feature-request, flags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Flag removal: Is it possible to remove your flag or otherwise indicate it should be unflagged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87660/flag-removal-is-it-possible-to-remove-your-flag-or-otherwise-indicate-it-should)
>   [Change or reverse flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96190/change-or-reverse-flag)

I recently flagged a question by accident (I didn't read it properly) and wanted to retract that flag but there is no way to do that. I saw [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87660/flag-removal-is-it-possible-to-remove-your-flag-or-otherwise-indicate-it-should) post which suggests re-flagging the question and explaining yourself, but you can't do that.

What does everyone think to having the ability to correct your mistaken flags? I would assume it would cut down on spam that the moderators must have to go through too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be nice to be able to retract our mistakes whenever we wanted too, but Jeff has voice his opinion against [implementing a way to retract close votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-rescind-a-close-vote-before-it-closes) (and that question has 250+ upvotes). I think the whole idea of preventing retracts is so that people will think about what they're doing before they actually do it. In the case of close votes, you can always vote to reopen, but in the case of moderator flags you'll use 10 flag weight for the invalid flag.

Misreading something can't really be considered a good reason *not* to lose flag weight, because that's the exact type of thing they'd be trying to prevent by disallowing retracts. All I can say is read more carefully next time, and it's not like losing 10 flag weight for a bad flag is the end of the world. I'd be more worried about losing 2 reputation from a downvote than 10 flag weight. Sure, retracting a flag is a good way to prevent moderators from having to look at it, but I think they're more worried about the bigger picture.

Comment: I wasn't worried about my flag weight I just felt bad for flagging something I shouldn't have. I didn't even think about it being used to maintain stats. Plus I searched for about 30 mins for a question the same and didn't find it.

Comment: This is red herring. It is not just about "reading carefully", but also about the OP updating the question after a while which is out of your control...