# What is the status of the revoke-flag feature request?

Tags: discussion, flags

[This is the one I mean](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110065/218740)

I [flagged an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19835913/2065121) as link-only and another user had obviously thought the same and added a comment later.

Perhaps I should have commented rather than flagged, but however, having done so, the OP responded to the comment and revised the answer, making my flag redundant.

Rather than let this get noticed and declined, it would be so much better if I could have revoked the flag to reduce the moderator's queue.

Looking for a way to do so, I found the above feature request, which seems quite popular. Is there any way to find out if/when it might get done?

Comment: Until is says on that feature request that it has been implemented, it hasn't been.

Comment: And if you think that particular request deserves new attention, perhaps consider the option to put a bounty on it.

Comment: @Bart Would a bounty make the feature more likely to be implemented or just make the question more likely to be answered?

Comment: It just brings new attention to it. There are no  guarantees it will affect anything on the dev-side.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes I understand that, it's just that it's quite an old request and there's no way to see if it's anywhere near to being done ...

Comment: [This is probably part of the reason](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfeature-request%5D+score%3A1..+is%3Aquestion+-%5Bstatus-completed%5D+-%5Bstatus-bydesign%5D+-%5Bstatus-declined%5D+-%5Bstatus-norepro%5D+-%5Bstatus-deferred%5D+-%5Bstatus-planned%5D+-%5Bstatus-review%5D+-%5Bstatus-reproduced%5D)

Comment: @RogerRowland: We the community get to suggest new features, but the developers are free to pick and choose what they actually implement. The rarely give progress reports, there is no way for us to see *if* a feature will be implemented, what priorities they have, when, if ever, the feature will be added.

Comment: @RogerRowland: there are many **tens of thousands** of feature requests here on Meta, they cannot possibly keep us abreast of all of them.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks - I *do* understand, I just thought it worth asking. After all, it would save mods some work, which would be helpful for all.

Comment: @Bart FWIW I've added a bounty ....

Comment: and this one isn't all that old.  It is from 2011.  There are still plenty from 2009 & 2010 that haven't be implemented yet (almost 2500 by my count)

Comment: Perfect @RogerRowland. And now we wait.....

Comment: @Bart I just noticed somebody cancelled my bounty and gave my rep back ... nice, but ... why? Do you know anything about it?

Comment: @RogerRowland I would assume the moderator (Random) did so, to be able to close the question as a duplicate.