# Can the spam flag description be reworded?

Tags: discussion, flags, spam, self-promotion

For `flag > spam`, the description is as follows:

> This answer is effectively an advertisement with no disclosure. It is not useful or relevant, but promotional.

This is good for a post such as this...

> Buy the [jQuery basic arithmetic plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekIbG.gif) NOW for $19.99!!!!!!!!!11

...which is obviously said advertisement. But what about this...

> Me love lorem ipsum. lorem ipsum! lorem ipsum!

...which is also spam, but **not** a "promotional" "advertisement." I generally flag these as spam and they are handled appropriately. Which leads me to my question:

Should either...

1. The description of `spam` gets changed to follow the dictionary definition? For example,

   > This answer is effectively an advertisement with no disclosure, or it is otherwise neither useful nor relevant.
2. Use a different flag reason? (Offensive/abusive? Not an answer? Very low quality?)

Comment: The latter is abusive, but not advertising. I think the consensus is to flag it as abusive.

Comment: How is that spam?

Answer (score 10):

You should be using the offensive/abusive flag for these kinds of posts, [Shog said so](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234032/why-dont-we-treat-rubbish-the-same-as-spam/234035#234035):

> If someone is abusing the site by posting gibberish, flag it as such. Any combination of 6 spam or offensive flags will delete and lock the post along with imposing various penalties and restrictions.

I do agree that this could be improved by adding something explicitly saying that gibberish should be flagged with that reason:

[image]

(we'd probably need to find something more universally recognizable than 'gibberish', but you get the point)

Comment: Nonsense/nonsensical? Intelligible maybe?

Comment: @JonK don't forget to exclude bad english and foreign language. Unintelligible includes bad english.

Comment: @JanDvorak D'oh! I meant unintelligible. I blame Mondays. Could the quote from Shog also extend to posts that aren't in the sites main language? Poor language is at least sometimes rescuable with a good edit, although the post will be a downvote magnet until then. That said, "unclear what you're asking" is probably a better fit for those questions.

Comment: @JonK No, it shouldn't extend to posts in other languages. Those should be flagged as VLQ. We don't really want people to get their IPs marked in SpamRam just because they wrote an answer in the wrong language.

Comment: @JonK don't use "abusive" for mistakes in good faith. Foreign language is unclear (cv+dv+comment) but not an abuse.

Comment: @Undo and Jan: That's fair enough - I rarely find the need to use the abusive/offensive flag anyway (I think I've used it once on a particularly nasty comment, but that's about it).