# Can the offensive flag description be reworded?

Tags: discussion, flags, offensive

The description of the "it is offensive, abusive, or hate speech" flag is this:

> This answer contains content that a reasonable person would deem inappropriate for respectful discourse.

However, [shog posted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234035/202832) that said flag **is** correct for "someone [who] is abusing the site by posting gibberish." Therefore an answer such as

> Me love lorem ipsum. lorem ipsum! lorem ipsum!

fits nicely into "abusive". However, the inline description of this flag remains unclear. I would still be flagging these as spam if it weren't for [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/243348/202832).

I propose that the wording of this tag is changed:

> This answer contains content that a reasonable person would deem inappropriate for respectful discourse, or is irrelevant gibberish.

---

Notice: irrelevant gibberish is still to be welcomed on meta... if you're a reasonable person.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> This answer contains content that a reasonable person would deem inappropriate for respectful discourse, or is irrelevant garbage.

If you're twisted up about flagging an answer because **you somehow consider irrelevant garbage to be appropriate for respectful discourse**, then the *last* thing I want to do is try to guide you in the direction of the Offensive flag. I mean... Who knows what you *do* think is inappropriate? For that matter, who knows what you think is garbage? All bets are off at this point - best to steer you away from the sharp objects.

Very Low Quality and Not An Answer both work for this as well; if you're not 100% on the applicability of *any* flag, just don't use it.

There's no single reason why folks post this stuff; therefore, expecting a one-size-fits-all flag isn't realistic either. This is why we have multiple flag-types, with Spam/Offensive->NAA->VLQ->Other being increasingly general-purpose.

Comment: Thus why I considered it spam before, rather than NAA or VLQ. I wouldn't consider gibberish unrespectful; it's not a dig at any other user. And it's also not spam, as you pointed out yourself.

Comment: In some cases, it actually *is* spam. As crazy as that sounds, if you've been in the position to see a lot of forum spam you'll tend to recognize the signs of someone "testing the waters". But again, if you *don't* recognize this then it's best to use a different flag - no harm done.

Answer (score 0):

Irrelevant garbage should be flagged as "not an answer." Irrelevance isn't offensive, only annoying.

Being abusive to someone is saying things like "You're a stupid idiot, and your father smells of elderberries!," not "flurple finkle!"

Comment: "Irrelevance isn't offensive" No, but it's abusive. If that is the case, the flag title should read only "offensive or hate speech".

Comment: @Moose No it isn't. Who is it abusing? (Being abusive is saying things like "you're a stupid idiot," not "flimble jamble!")

Comment: Also, the presence of "or is irrelevant garbage" would cause people to start using this for bad answers or ones they disagree with (based on their own personal interpretation of "garbage").

Comment: hmmm @BradLarson how about "nonsensical concatenations of characters"? "dadaistic poetry"? ...

Comment: @Emrakul Apparently, the answer to "who is being abused?" can be "the site". [If someone is abusing the site by posting gibberish, flag it as such.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234032/why-dont-we-treat-rubbish-the-same-as-spam/234035#234035)