# Remove the point about the author's affiliation from spam flag description on questions

Tags: feature-request, flags, spam

Currently the flag > spam dialog has the following description:

[image: Dialog Image]

We had a discussion about it in a chat room and came to the conclusion that the author's affiliation has no effect **when flagging a question**. It doesn't make a difference whether you're advertising your own product or someone else's in my opinion. The case is of course very much different when we're talking about flagging an answer.

The latter point in the description is very confusing to me, and it took me a while to realize it was actually meant for flagging answers.

(Note that I found [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243345/can-the-spam-flag-description-be-reworded), but my question here is very different.)

Could the "does not disclose the author's affiliation" point be removed from the **question** flagging dialog?

Comment: There should be an "or" there, but I feel like we had some reason for not putting one. Can't remember what that could've been though.

Comment: I value seeing when an answer describes the author's affiliation and would prefer posts where this isn't clear maintain some form of moderation to promote that level of transparency.

Comment: What's the status of this request, status-ignored?