# Abusive, but not rude

Tags: feature-request, support, flags, spam, offensive

I came across a post, which was basically gibberish like "hsuheuduehuhfuheufhufe".  Originally I marked it as spam, but it was not accepted.  Why?  It should have been marked at rude and abusive.  Perhaps a new feature could be to separate the 2, so that such a post, which is definitely abusive, but not rude?  Thanks.

Comment: It says rude OR abusive, not and, so you can use that flag for either reason.

Comment: However, I would also like to know why that cannot be spam

Comment: You should ask the people on the site that rejected the flag, sites have their own definitions of spam.

Comment: _"why that cannot be spam"_ Because "spam" is unsolicited commercial advertising, not banging mindlessly on the keyboard.

Comment: okay... but many of the time people talk about like "dont spam me" on social media so gibberish is sort-of spam

Comment: I think moderators tend to forget this guidance, that's why I prefer to add a comment under flagged post: [Why don't we treat rubbish the same as spam?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234035/165773)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rude and abusive are (to some extent) the same thing. You've already known that you should flag gibberish as *rude or abusive*. That's a good start. You should also know that gibberish adds *no* value to the sites. It actively harms the overall quality of user-generated content on Stack Exchange, thus abusive.

Flags are meant to report specifically bad posts or behavior on Stack Exchange, so use them accordingly. Flag real spam as *spam*, and flag offensive (with bad words) or garbage posts as *rude or abusive*.

On Stack Exchange, the term "spam" specifically means "unsolicited commercial advertising". Don't confuse it with that "spam" you see in social media.

Comment: Perhaps we could separate them so it wouldnt be so misleading

Comment: @XcoderX Answer updated.