# What happens if I flag posts as "trash"?

Tags: support, flags, moderation, low-quality-posts

What happens if I flag as "In need of moderator intervention" and then type "trash"? What kind of posts should I flag as "trash"?

Comment: That's not specific or detailed!

Comment: @ElementsinSpace I was tempted to vote to close this with custom reason "trash" but that won't be friendly, sadly.

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars At least that'd be specific.

Comment: see [Why don't we treat rubbish the same as spam?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234035/165773)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You think you're being funny. Nice try. See, Stack Exchange thought about people like you:

[image: Image of the flag dialog, focused on the "moderator intervention" flag with 'trash' input, indicating that a post can't be flagged with that little text]

As it turns out, "trash" isn't a long enough reason to raise a flag at the system-level. So... Nothing would happen! Ha!

*Ahem...*

In all seriousness, if I were a moderator, I'd certainly decline a flag that said little more than "trash". That's not describing a problem that needs a moderator's attention. If a post is low quality, needs closed, etc. We have regular flags for that.

Moderator intervention flags are meant to communicate a serious problem that isn't covered by normal flags to [one of our site moderators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/site-moderators). Situations that require them should be exceptional, which is why moderators are sometimes called [human exception handlers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/18/a-theory-of-moderation/). Please use them only for situations in which a moderator really needs to get involved, and when you do, please be as specific as possible about what you feel is problematic. If it's not obvious, do also include what action you'd like the moderator to take that you can't.

> What kind of posts should I flag as "trash"?

None! If there's a problem with it, there's certainly better options in the flag dialog available to you than to call it "trash", even if you do truly feel that it's a "trash" post.

Comment: It's also probably worth noting that flags like this, especially when targeted against a specific user (or group of users), _may_ also result in warnings and/or suspensions for abusing flag privileges.

Comment: Also practically the use of that flag reason is when the existing flags don't cover it (very low quality, and the spam/rude flag reasons cover a lot), or there's some specific detail that's needed, like its a troll you're aware of, or a CM escalation might be needed and you don't want to mods to miss it cause it was instakilled by flags