# Take back/revert our flags

Tags: support, flags, undo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cancel misclicked flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87500/cancel-misclicked-flags)
>   [Flag removal: Is it possible to remove your flag or otherwise indicate it should be unflagged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87660/flag-removal-is-it-possible-to-remove-your-flag-or-otherwise-indicate-it-should)

Whenever we flag a question as something inappropriate, is it possible to take back/revert that flag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not possible. Be careful when flagging.