# Any way to unflag a question?

Tags: discussion, flags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Flag removal: Is it possible to remove your flag or otherwise indicate it should be unflagged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87660/flag-removal-is-it-possible-to-remove-your-flag-or-otherwise-indicate-it-should)

I flagged this question [Using pascal data into php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12123811/using-pascal-data-into-php).

When the content was:

> Kept private now. Thanks for the help!

Seconds later, someone rolled it back to the original (good) question. Of course now the flag is marked as disputed. Until now, all my flags have been marked helpful (at least since that functionality was added). Was there any way I could've unflagged when the quality of the question improved ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there's no way to unflag a post.  There are three flag resolutions, helpful, declined, and disputed.  Disputed is neutral, so it won't count against you once that specific flag is resolved.

Comment: Thanks - I hadn't realised there were 3 outcomes.

Comment: @Basic It would be preferable to rollback the misguided edit instead of flagging, no point in asking a moderator to do something for you that you can already do on your own. It would make sense to flag for moderation attention and ask for the question to be locked if the OP continued to vandalize the question (as he did, but Bill's already on top of that, so...)

Comment: @YannisRizos Yeah, that occured to me about 10 seconds later - which is actually why I went back to the Q. The only reason it didn't in the first place was the "private" aspect but I should've checked the edit history and seen it wasn't really.